# Show that $\overline{Y} = Y \cup \{ (0,y): -1\le y \le 1\}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $Y= \{ (x,y): y = \sin(1/x), 0 < x \le 1\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. Show that $\overline{Y} = Y \cup \{ (0,y): -1\le y \le 1\}$.

I know that $\overline{Y} = Y \cup Y' $, where $Y'$ denotes the set of limit points of $Y$.

So I'm assuming we need to show that $Y' = \{ (0,y): -1\le y \le 1\}$. How can I show this though?

Answer (score 1):

First note that $Y'\subset\{(0,y)\vert -1\leq y\leq 1 \}$.

Let $x_k(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha+k2\pi}$ then we have that for all $\alpha$ and for all $k:\sin(\frac{1}{x_k(\alpha)})=\sin(\alpha)$, moreover $x_k(\alpha)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$. Therefore by picking a large enough $k$ we have that for all $\alpha\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ we can find $k_\alpha$ such that $\forall k\geq k_\alpha: 0\leq x_k(\alpha)\leq 1$.

This gives you that $Y'=\{(0,y)\vert -1\leq y\leq 1 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n,y_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence on $Y$, converging to $(x,y)$. As $Y\subseteq [0,1]\times [-1,1]$, we find that $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [-1,1]$ as well.

First suppose that $x\neq 0$. Then we find by continuity that $y=\sin (1/x)$. In particular, we find that $(x,y)\in Y$. This proves that $\overline{Y}\subseteq Y\cup \{0\}\times [-1,1]$.

For the converse, let $(0,y)\in \{0\}\times [-1,1]$. Consider the sequence $(x_n)_n=(\frac{1}{\arcsin(y)+(n+1)2\pi}, y)_n$. This sequence consists of elements of $Y$, is well defined, and converges to $(0,y)$. As a result, we find $Y\cup\{0\}\times [-1,1]\cup Y\subseteq \overline{Y}$.

PS: Spotty was ahead of me :(.